# Onclick change or insert text in dynamic table cell span

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamic table, with multiple tr and td and buttons in it. I want to insert a counting number infront of td content, every time the (up)-button is clicked. Something like this: [3 x ABC].

My demo does not work, but my current version; what ever button I click on, the number appears and increase in all of the rows at once. I want the buttons to function in respektiv rows.
How to manage that in jquery? Please.

```
$(function(){
    var count=1;
    $('.up').click(function(){
    count++
    $('.times').text(count+' x ');
})
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mazlomak/j9vnbcf0/4/)**

Comment: Come on, you *must* have noticed that the styling of the button also doesn't work. You type `claas` instead of `class`. That's not the only issue, but I'd start there... If you then also add jQuery to your fiddle, at least you've got [something to debug](https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/3/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
$('.times').text(count+' x ');
```

It selects *every* occurrance of `.times` and sets a text to all of them.

In your case, you want the one on the same row. So from the clicked element (`this`), go up and find the closest `tr` in the chain of ancestors. Then, within that row, find a `.times` again to set the text in:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count+' x ');
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/5/)

If you want to have a counter per row too, you could store the counter information in a data attribute of the element. Another, arguably better, solution is to create closures that hold the variable. That latter solution I've implemented in...

[Yet another update of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the count continues on the other rows, that's not exactly what is expected. Every row should start from 1 and increase by every click.? any suggestions?

Comment: That's good, but for that ask a new question, otherwise this will become a mess. :)

Comment: I am back, :) 
I have another bug that I have been struggling with for 3 days. How do I make this up button to update the attr value. When I increase the count and then decrease it, and then increase it again, it does not increase from the current value of attr value. I just don't know how to update it after down button been clicked.  [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/8/)